# Array parsing php

Tags: php

How to get from array:

```
$a = [
'color' => ['red', 'blue', ....∞],
'size' => ['10 -12 ', '12 -14', ....∞],
.....∞
];
```

such an array

```
$b = [
['color' => 'red', 'size' => '10 -12 '],
['color' => 'blue', 'size' => '10 -12 '],
['color' => 'red', 'size' => '12 -14 '],
['color' => 'blue', 'size' => '12 -14 '],
];
```

keys and values can be any number,
the names of keys and values can be different

php cross join

I tried to do it, but it's limited

```
foreach($a['color'] as $k1 => $v1){ 
  foreach($a['size'] as $k2 => $v2){ 
    $d[] = ['color' => $v1, 'size' => $v2]; 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Should there even be  a trailing space at the end of the values?

Comment: why my question is dislike, what happened?

Comment: [Because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Basically, state your problem, the outcome and describe what you tried so far to fix it.

Comment: tl;dr, you've shown no effort in your question to imply that you've tried to fix the problem yourself, you're just posting code and saying what you want to happen, what have you tried so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: lol @zack6849 your tl;dr is the longest comment

Comment: Much shorter than the entire how to ask though :)

Comment: I added attempts

Comment: @Voldant  I THINK YOU WANT LIKE THIS:- https://eval.in/925409

Comment: @Alive to Die--Anant singh, this is a special case, there can be many keys and values on the task

Comment: @Voldant  WORK FOR THAT TOO.foreach will take care for indexes

Comment: it's like a cross-connection in sql, how to do this in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no one here can solve it, apparently it's difficult, I found a solution

**Solution 1**

```
function cross($array)
{
    $result     = [];
    $current    = array_splice($array, -1);

    foreach ($current as $key => $values) {
        foreach ( $values as $value) {
            if (empty($array)) {
                array_push($result, [$key => $value]);
            } else {
                foreach (cross($array) as $temp) {
                    array_push($result, array_merge([$key => $value], $temp));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(cross($a));
```

**Solution 2**

```
function cartesian($input) {
    $result = array();

    while (list($key, $values) = each($input)) {
        // If a sub-array is empty, it doesn't affect the cartesian product
        if (empty($values)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Seeding the product array with the values from the first sub-array
        if (empty($result)) {
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $result[] = array($key => $value);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Second and subsequent input sub-arrays work like this:
            //   1. In each existing array inside $product, add an item with
            //      key == $key and value == first item in input sub-array
            //   2. Then, for each remaining item in current input sub-array,
            //      add a copy of each existing array inside $product with
            //      key == $key and value == first item of input sub-array

            // Store all items to be added to $product here; adding them
            // inside the foreach will result in an infinite loop
            $append = array();

            foreach($result as &$product) {
                // Do step 1 above. array_shift is not the most efficient, but
                // it allows us to iterate over the rest of the items with a
                // simple foreach, making the code short and easy to read.
                $product[$key] = array_shift($values);

                // $product is by reference (that's why the key we added above
                // will appear in the end result), so make a copy of it here
                $copy = $product;

                // Do step 2 above.
                foreach($values as $item) {
                    $copy[$key] = $item;
                    $append[] = $copy;
                }

                // Undo the side effecst of array_shift
                array_unshift($values, $product[$key]);
            }

            // Out of the foreach, we can add to $results now
            $result = array_merge($result, $append);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? Note that for it to work correctly, the number of parameters for color and size must be the same!

```
<?php

$b = ['color' => ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],'size' => ['10 -12 ', '12 -14', '12-16']];

for ($counter=0; $counter < sizeof($b['color']) ; $counter++) { 
    $d[$counter]['color'] = $b['color'][$counter];
    $d[$counter]['size'] = $b['size'][$counter];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($d);

?>
```

Comment: keys and values can be any